# Blank context menu items in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, context-menu

From time to time, and recently constantly, the context menu in Explorer on my Mac Pro running Windows 10 is missing most of the items - they are simply blank:

[image: Missing or blank items from context menu in Explorer]

I've also experienced that graphic disappears in other programs. In addition I've experienced a lot of application crashes in Visual Studio 2015 and Skype for Business 2016. Wondering if there is a connection.

I upgraded the machine from Windows 8. Not a clean install.

### Edit: Disabling shell extensions

I followed [this guide](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/slowrightclick.htm) and ran [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html#DownloadLinks) to disable any non-Microsoft shell extensions, but to no avail. Now the context menu is even funnier:

[image: Slightly weirder context menu]

Comment: Definitely sounds like a graphics driver issue, try uninstalling your current graphics driver and reinstall the latest available from their website. I've had this in the past with Windows version, and all cases have been the graphics driver.

Comment: New drivers fixed the issue. Thanks @AaronLayfield. Post your comment as an answer, and I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Added my answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely a driver issue. Windows is displaying the appropriately sized list, its just the graphics incorrectly rendering.

Like cause: Windows 7/8 drivers on a Windows 10 system.

Reinstalling the latest drivers from your graphics card vendor should definitely resolve this.

Comment: Great solution. Let me emphasize that I was running Windows 10 on a Mac Pro with Bootcamp. I had seen the "new updates from beloved Apple Installer" a few times, but flatly refused to look at it, thinking it was only offering me iCloud and iTunes - which I don't want.